# Parsing Text FIle Using Awk

Tags: parsing, awk

I would like to parse a text file that has the section of interest as follows:

```
mesh 0 400 12000
400 300 400
1 0 -1
300 500 600
0 0 1
etc....
12000
1300
1100
etc..
```

I would only like the rows that immediately follow the row that starts with string `mesh` and every other one after that as well, and has 3 columns. I would like this output to be in a separate text file with a modified name.

So desired output text file:

```
400 300 400
300 500 600
```

I tried to do this with python and loops but it literally took hours and never finished as there are thousand to hundred of thousands of lines in the original text file.

Is there a more efficient way to do this in with a bash script using awk?

Comment: Why are `1 0 -1` and `0 0 1` not in the output? They have three columns as well.

Comment: I would like only every other row after mesh. So in python I know I could specify this by using the mod function. If mesh is counted as row 1 then the next row would be 2 and after 3,4,5 etc. I am only interested in the even rows (%2) that contain 3 colmuns (as the rows then become a single column at some point)

Comment: Python has regular-expression capability also.  The problem looks like it can be solved with a fairly simple Python script – no need to use bash and awk.  First you scan to find a line that begins with `mesh`, and that, so to speak, "turns on the switch."  Now, perhaps in a nested loop, you start looking for lines.  A function like `split` might be easy – or a regex that looks for three groups of digits separated by whitespace.  Take a deep breath and try again.  Or, post an *excerpt* of your first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^mesh/{n=NR;next} NF==3 && n && NR%2==(n+1)%2' file > filtered_file
400 300 400
300 500 600
```

Comment: Thank you!! this is exactly what I needed! I tried something like this initially but was not familiar enough with the syntax to get  it to work. Output to new file works as well!